# Wix/Detox - Android tests fail to typeText or replaceText

Tags: android, detox

Works on iOS, but gives the following error on Android when trying to type into the input field.

> Failed: [Error: Error: Error performing 'replace text' on view '(with
>   tag value: is "firstName" and view has effective
>   visibility=VISIBLE)'.]

SDK 28
detox 9.0.5

Comment: This is unfortunately a [known issue](https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/1185).